# If I refresh a page continuously, does HTTP GET method invokes doGet() method of a servlet every time for every refresh?

Tags: http, servlets, post, get

I'm trying to post some data using HTTP GET method. Of course, I should choose POST method to post the data.

Here the question is, if I refresh a page continuously, for every refresh, does HTTP GET method invokes doGet() method of a servlet every time?

My understanding is that in case of POST method, every time it invokes doPOst() method of a servlet for every refresh.

My html page looks like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>user registration</title>
</head>
<body>
 <form action="hello" method="get">
  User Name: <input type="text" name="userName" /> <br> <br> User Id: <input
   type="text" name="userId" /> <br><br>
   Select the profession: 
   <input type="radio" value="Developer" name="proffession">Developer
   <input type="radio" value= "Architect" name="profession">Architect<br><br>
   Select your location: 
   <select name="location" multiple size=3>
   <option value="Bangalore">Bangalore</option>
   <option value="Mangalore">Mangalore</option>
   <option value="Udupi">Udupi</option>
   <option value="Bhatkal">Bhatkal</option>
   </select><br><br>
   <input type="submit">
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is Yes. doGet() method will be invoked for every page refresh in case of GET method as well!

We can debug this scenario by initializing a global variable in init() method and increment the global variable every time either doGet() or doPost() method is called.

Following code demonstrate the same:

```html
package org.shan.jspservlets;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class XmlServlet extends HttpServlet {
    
    private int hitCount; 
    
      public void init() 
      { 
         // Reset hit counter.
         hitCount = 0;
      } 
      
      
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String userName = request.getParameter("userName");
        String userId = request.getParameter("userId");
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        hitCount++; 
        response.getWriter().print(
                "<html><body><h1> Hello from XML servlet to " + userName
                        + "</h1></body></html>");
        response.getWriter().print(
                "<html><body><h1> Your id is: " + userId
                        + "</h1></body></html>");
        response.getWriter().print("hitcount: "+ hitCount);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String userName = request.getParameter("userName");
        String userId = request.getParameter("userId");
        String profession = request.getParameter("profession");
        // String location = request.getParameter("location");
        String location[] = request.getParameterValues("location");
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        response.getWriter().print(
                "<html><body><h1> Hello from XML servlet to " + userName
                        + "</h1></body></html>");
        response.getWriter().print(
                "<html><body><h1> Your id is: " + userId
                        + "</h1></body></html>");
        response.getWriter().print(
                "<html><body><h1> Your profession is: " + profession
                        + "</h1></body></html>");
        response.getWriter().print(
                "<html><body><h1> Your at following " + location.length
                        + " palces!!!</h1></body></html>");
        for (int i = 0; i < location.length; i++)
            response.getWriter().print(
                    "<html><body><h1>" + location[i]
                            + "</h1></body></html>");
    }

}
```

You can observe that for very page refresh, the hitCount is getting incremented!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you are hitting the refresh Button(F5 or Ctrl+R) then deferentially it will hit the application through GET method only, even you mention the POST in form but you are hitting the app page with the URL only.

Comment: Does it calls doGet() method, every time we refresh the page?

Comment: When ever we refresh the page then it will look for the requested resource and it will open the page with the fresh data, and deferentially it will be a kind of GET only.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the [spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) is specific on this, but why not have a debug statement in your code and find out? I think that's the fastest way of finding out what happens in your specific setup

Comment: The HTTP spec is really unrelated to this question (and the version you're referring to is outdated)

Comment: How is it unrelated? If the spec says that a GET request with a body should not be cached, you'd expect that goGet is called every time, right? If it doesn't it's up to the implementer of the appserver.

Comment: You can't send a request body with a GET request from an HTML form anyway, so I don't believe that was what the question was about.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, responded too soon, without proper reading. Sorry!